# Horizontal scrolling does not work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, navigation

I'm having a bit a of problem with a navigation not working as it should. If you view the following site on a non-mobile browser, you'll get an idea on how the navigation should function.

[www.snottrocket.com](http://www.snottrocket.com)

The problem is with mobile platforms. I've viewed this site on an android phone and iPad and it doesn't work as it does in a desktop browser. I do recall that it worked fine with the android before but it may be that the phone's browser has been updated or something.

I thought that maybe it had to do with URL masking but I'm not sure.  Essentially, this site lives in a directory under another website and uses URL masking to display snottrocket.com in the url window.  This is done with an iFrame but i'm not sure if it's the reason.

I'm assuming the other reason may be the JS code for the scrolling functionality.

Either way, i'm kind of stuck.  Anyone want to take a crack at it and tell me what I'm missing or how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works fine for me in Chrome on Android, though it's really tiny and hard to read. *edit* oh wait, you mean the menu, not the scrolling.

Comment: You're using a really old version of jQuery, the old version of fancybox, and that scroll library itself looks pretty dicey.

Comment: Admittedly, it's old, yes.  I built that site about three years ago.  

So update the JQuery is first and foremost.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Well clearly that scroll library is getting confused by what the mobile browsers are telling it. You may have to directly debug it to figure out what's wrong. Such debugging can be tedious; [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/) is the simplest tool to use. It's no picnic but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Ha,that's beyond my understanding.  I may need find another option that offers the same functionality and retro-fit.  Or it may be the universe's way of telling me to scrap it and start over.